# Transaction X attempted to access an object created by transaction Y via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, sap-iq

I have JDBC code which talks to Sybase IQ. One of the thread is loading/update data into one Sybase IQ table say t1. Other threads will try to fire SQL query on table t1 after the first finished loading/updating data.

```
Write thread:
Create table t1, load/update data into t1, commit to t1.

Read thread(s):
Read select query from t1
```

I am getting the following error as mentioned in [here](http://www.doblerconsulting.com/tech-tips-tricks/sybase-tips/sybase-iq-versioning-and-locks/):

```
Transaction 156593 attempted to access an object created by transaction 156608.
-- (db_txnInfo.cxx 690)
Sybase error code=21, SQLState=”QDA11”
```

I am not sure where is the problem I am committing after every load. Every thread uses different connection read thread fires only `select` query then where is the problem how do I debug? I am new to Sybase IQ and JDBC.

Comment: Are you 100 sure the commit is complete when you are doing the select?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to issue a commit in the second thread. Or for the read-only thread set auto-commit on.

I'm curious, does the error happen on the **first** select from the second thread, or does it only happen **after** the first select?

In IQ, even a select statement can generate a transaction (which it should really handle a bit better as IQ is supposed to create "snapshot versions" to give a transaction a logitudinally consistent view on the data for the life of a transaction ... IQ has some F$%@#$%ng ugly warts by the way)